# How to only print analytical solutions using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to create a code that keep on trying to solve a differential equation for different values of a parameter, in this case $ a $. But it must print only when it has an analytical solution.

A simple example follows:

```
V[x_] := Sin[x]^a;
Do[{Print["a = ", a],
  Print[V[x]],
  Print[DSolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x, x\)]\(ψ[
         x]\)\) + (V[x] - ω^2) ψ[x] == 0, ψ[x], x]] //
    FullSimplify},
 {a, 0, 2}
 ]
```

It is obvious that this has an analytical solution for $ a = 0 $, but it will still print something for the other values. How do I get an `If` condition that tells Mathematica to not print if an analytical solution was not found?

And any other suggestion on how to make this more efficient is welcome, since my problem is far more complicated than this.

Comment: Replace `Print[DSolve[...]]` with `FullSimplify[
  DSolve[\[Psi]''[x] + (V[x] - \[Omega]^2) \[Psi][x] == 0, \[Psi][x], 
   x]] /. res_?ListQ :> Print[res]`?  Note your original `FullSimplify` was outside `Print` and had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

V[x_] := Sin[x]^a;

Module[{temp},
 Table[temp = DSolveValue[
      ψ''[x] + (V[x] - ω^2) ψ[x] == 0, ψ[x], x];
    If[FreeQ[temp, _DSolveValue], {a, (sol[a] = temp // FullSimplify) // 
       TraditionalForm}, Nothing],
    {a, -4, 4}] //
   Prepend[#, (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"a", "ψ(x)"})] & //
  Grid[#, Frame -> All] &]
```

[image]

The results are stored in `sol`

```
?sol
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For an incremental output

```
Module[{temp}, Table[temp = DSolveValue[
    ψ''[x] + (V[x] - ω^2) ψ[x] == 0, ψ[x], x];
  If[FreeQ[temp, _DSolveValue], Print[StringForm[
     "With a=``, ψ(x)=``;", 
     a, (sol[a] = temp // FullSimplify) // TraditionalForm]]; Nothing, 
   Nothing], {a, -4, 4}]]
```

[image]

The results are still stored in the indexed variable `sol`

Comment: It works, but I have no idea why. Could you briefly explain me, please? It it possible to change it to print a found solution whenever it is found, since my problem is going to take much longer to run, and I would like to check if it found something on the go.

Comment: In the `Table`, (1) `a` is given its value, (2) `DSolveValue` attempts to find `\[Psi][x]` and `temp` is temporarily `Set` to either `\[Psi][x]` or the unevaluated `DSolveValue`, (3) `If` `temp` does not contain an expression with `Head` of `DSolveValue`, the indexed variable `sol` is `Set` to `temp` (i.e., `\[Psi][x]`), (4) the `If` evaluates to either `{a, \[Psi][x]}` or `Nothing`; the rest is formatting of the `Grid`.